# iOS Webview Zoom Level

Tags: objective-c, uiwebview

How can I find the zoom level of `webview's` `scrollView` programmatically. I tried with below code.

My code:

```
[WebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[Nssting stringWithFormat:@"document.body.style.zoom = %f;",zoomlevel];
```

Comment: your ques not clear and also not well formatted ..

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I need to find the zoom level programmatically. If my content is small zoom level must be 4.0 or 5.0. like that

Comment: check my ans if suitable ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got the answer.

May be it will help anyone.

Here is my answer:

add this meta tag in your html string.

meta name='viewport' content='width=300,minimum-scale=0.25,maximum-scale=3.0,user-scalable=yes'

Thanks,
AKS

Answer (score 0):

Get the `scrolView` of `webView` then apply some actions over it using below code. Here are some ways you can apply.

Detect you content size and set the zoom level:

```
UIScrollView *sview = [[webview subviews] objectAtIndex:0];
```

---

```
[self.webView.scrollView setZoomScale:1.5 animated:YES];
```

**Some more:**

```
for (UIView *subView in [self.view subviews]) {
    if ([subView isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]]) {

        UIScrollView *scrollView = (UIScrollView *)subView;
        [scrollView setZoomScale:2.5f animated:YES];
    }
}
```

**Note:** Internal `scrollview` is the `subview` of `webview`.

**Edit:**

Just use delegate methods of `webview` to get height and width see below code:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)aWebView
{        
    CGFloat height = [[aWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.height"] floatValue];
    CGFloat width = [[aWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.width"] floatValue];
    CGRect frame = aWebView.frame;
    frame.size.height = height;
    frame.size.width = width;
    aWebView.frame = frame;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. In your code you are hard coded zoom level (1.5 and 2.5 f). I need to find it dynamically depending on the size of html content. Is there anyway to find zoom level?

Comment: welcome, this is just en example as per your provided information above  so here is not code writing services going on you need to make it dynamic as much as you can ..

Comment: In my app I am using the code that you replied. But it fails in some condition. Thats why I am searching for a dynamic way. Sorry if it is not a correct place.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable time. It won't work for my app. Because in my app , the width of web view must be fixed. And content will be zoomed in that frame.